# Adding Custom Controls dll to Visual Studio ToolBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, controls

I have a custom control DLL. How can I add these custom controls to VS2008 tool box programatically?

Answer (score 47):

1. Right-click on toolbox
2. select "Choose Items"
3. browse to your DLL.
4. Add the items

Comment: FYI, still valid in vs2015.

Comment: But, It is asked how to add it `programatically`!

Comment: What does "programatically" mean in this situation anyway? This answer is perfectly fine.

Comment: I would interpret **programatically** as done by a program, not just done by a user clicking around within a program. That is; I run a program or script and when it has completed the desired result has occurred.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do it:

As explained at [MSDN Tutorial: Installing Controls By Using the Toolbox Controls Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286995%28VS.80%29.aspx) you do it from an installer.

There's also another possibility using a command line program available on [CodePlex](http://vstudiotoolbox.codeplex.com/). You use this application with your favorite installer or you can invoke it manually.

Comment: Links may have changed. First one directs to: Visual Studio 2005 Retired documentation

Answer (score 2):

In my Visual Studio 2019 I don't get any "choose items" when right-clicking "Toolbox".

I had to use `Tools` / `Choose Toolbox Items`

[image]

Comment: Thank you though for showing the other way to add items! I will say that in my version of 2019, I did have Choose Items on the toolbox. I wonder if maybe you were still initializing, or hadn't had a solution/project loaded up? You don't have the default controls in your Toolbox, so the Toolbox isn't full loaded for whatever reason.